# How do I generate a random integer between min and max in Java?

Tags: java, random

What method returns a random int between a min and max? Or does no such method exist?

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
NAMEOFMETHOD (min, max)
```

(where min and max are `int`s), that returns something like this:

```
8
```

(randomly)

If such a method does exist could you please link to the relevant documentation with your answer.

Thanks.

---

### UPDATE

Attempting to implement the full solution and I get the following error message:

```
class TestR
{
    public static void main (String[]arg) 
    {   
        Random random = new Random() ;
        int randomNumber = random.nextInt(5) + 2;
        System.out.println (randomNumber) ; 
    } 
}
```

I'm still getting the same errors from the compiler:

```
TestR.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Random
location: class TestR
        Random random = new Random() ;
        ^
TestR.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Random
location: class TestR
        Random random = new Random() ;
                            ^
TestR.java:6: operator + cannot be applied to Random.nextInt,int
        int randomNumber = random.nextInt(5) + 2;
                                         ^
TestR.java:6: incompatible types
found   : <nulltype>
required: int
        int randomNumber = random.nextInt(5) + 2;
                                             ^
4 errors
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Did you forget to declare `random` and assign a new instance of `java.util.Random` to it?

Comment: could you explain how to do that?

Comment: Did you declare import statements for java.util.Random

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Construct a Random object at application startup:

```
Random random = new Random();
```

Then use [Random.nextInt(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt--):

```
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(max + 1 - min) + min;
```

Note that the both lower and upper limits are inclusive.

Comment: i updated the question with the error that occurs when i try to do that what is going wrong?

Comment: David, you need to instantiate it first. `Random random = new Random();`  It's still *just* Java code. There's no means of magic ;)

Comment: And make sure that you only instantiate the Random object once and reuse it. Don't create a new Random object for each call to your function.

Comment: Yes, you can safely make it a `static` variable of the class as well.

Comment: could you edit yoru answer to show the whole thing put together?

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer. If you need more help, I suggest you read an article or tutorial about random numbers in Java, such as this one: http://www.cs.geneseo.edu/~baldwin/reference/random.html

Comment: i tried your answer so far as i can tell (updated OP) and it didnt' work. what did i do wrong?

Comment: You are missing `import java.util.Random;`.

Comment: @MarkByers is "only instantiate the Random object once and reuse it" a memory thing? Or it affects returned values? I couldn't find anything else on the subject (apart from another person saying it also, but not explaining why).

Comment: @ataulm: In older versions of Java creating multiple Random objects didn't guarantee randomness. "Two Random objects created within the same millisecond will have the same sequence of random numbers." ([source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random())). In newer versions it is probably OK, but I didn't know that when I wrote my comment three years ago.

Comment: this solution works for most of the cases, but is not robust to all values of min and max, ie max-min can overflow when max is large and min is negative, leading nextInt to throw an exception

Comment: Note that the bound of the Random.nextInt method is exclusive. The way it is used in this answer does make it so that the result can produce max as the output https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-

Answer (score 19):

You can use [Random.nextInt(n)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-). This returns a random int in [0,n). Just using max-min+1 in place of n and adding min to the answer will give a value in the desired range.

Comment: i updated the question with the error that occurs when i try to do that what is going wrong?

Answer (score 10):

```
public static int random_int(int Min, int Max)
{
     return (int) (Math.random()*(Max-Min))+Min;
}

random_int(5, 9); // For example
```

Comment: Your _algorithm_ is Random x * positive number + positive number. How can this always result in a number between max and min?

Comment: Random is between 0 and 1. Do the math.

Comment: Be aware that the lower limit is inclusive but the upper limit is exclusive in this answer. If you wants both to be inclusive use:
return (int) (Math.random()*(Max-Min + 1))+Min;

Answer (score 4):

As the solutions above do not consider the possible overflow of doing `max-min` when `min` is negative, here another solution (similar to the one of kerouac)

```
public static int getRandom(int min, int max) {
    if (min > max) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Min " + min + " greater than max " + max);
    }      
    return (int) ( (long) min + Math.random() * ((long)max - min + 1));
}
```

this works even if you call it with:

```
getRandom(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
```

Answer (score 4):

With Java 7 or above you could use

```
ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(int origin, int bound)
```

Javadoc: [ThreadLocalRandom.nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt(int,int))

Answer (score 1):

Using the Random class is the way to go as suggested in the accepted answer, but here is a less straight-forward correct way of doing it if you didn't want to create a new Random object :

```
min + (int) (Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
```

Answer (score -3):

This generates a random integer of size psize

```
public static Integer getRandom(Integer pSize) {

    if(pSize<=0) {
        return null;
    }
    Double min_d = Math.pow(10, pSize.doubleValue()-1D);
    Double max_d = (Math.pow(10, (pSize).doubleValue()))-1D;
    int min = min_d.intValue();
    int max = max_d.intValue();
    return RAND.nextInt(max-min) + min;
}
```

Comment: That seems a complex way of achieving something that can be done in a single line of code.  Please use code formatting in future.

Answer (score -6):

import java.util.Random;