# How do I generate a random number between -1 and 1?

Tags: java, arrays, random, grid, numbers

I am trying to generate a random grid and to represent an empty space, non-empty space and a space where a player is I am using -1, 0 and 1 respectively in a 2D array.

I want to be able to generate a random graph at run time and fill up up the grid with -1's and 0's. How should I go about doing this?

I've looked at some examples but they're confusing :S I know there's a Random class in Java but it doesn't have a method where I can do something like nextInt(-1, 1), where I can set the starting range.

Any help would be great.

Cheers

Comment: I love how people just neg others with no explanation even though the questions are well within requirements.

Comment: I love how people say how they love people even though they actually mean they hate those people.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i generate a random integer between min and max in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444019/how-do-i-generate-a-random-integer-between-min-and-max-in-java)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`nextInt(3) -1` will give you a random integer in the desired range.

The [`random.nextInt(3)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) will generate a random integer of 0/1/2, and by reducing 1 - you get an equal (uniform) probability to get each of -1/0/1

Comment: Example plus an explanation is always a plus

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
Random random = new Random();
int someInt = random.nextInt(3) - 1;
```