# How do I populate an array with the x amount of number that the user inputs with random integers?

Tags: java, arrays

In Java, I am trying to populate an array with random numbers. The array has to be the size that the user inputs. For example, if the user enters 6, then the array must have 6 numbers in it. This is what I have for this program so far. It compiles and runs, but prints out only 0's. I am a little new to Java.

```
{
    System.out.println("Enter a number: " );

    int number = scan.nextInt();

    int [] integerArray = new int[number];
    for (int i=0; i < number; i++)
    {
        integerArray[i] = (int)(Math.random());
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(integerArray));
}
```

Comment: `Math.random()` returns a double between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). So if you cast it to an int, it's always going to be 0. Multiply `Math.random()` by some amount, e.g. `number`.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444019/how-do-i-generate-a-random-integer-between-min-and-max-in-java as well

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.Random` has a method to supply an array with random integer values; consider the following:

```
Random random = new Random();

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

int[] array = random.ints(scanner.nextInt()).toArray();
```

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-) if you're curious.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()` returns a double between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive).

So if you cast it to an int, it's always going to be 0.

Multiply the result of `Math.random()` by some amount, e.g. `number`.