# Why does my Java program not produce a fixed number of random numbers?

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java, most of the time I don't know what I'm doing. I'm trying to make a code where you can choose how many numbers to generate, the maximum and the minimum number of a random number generated.

It keeps on generating the numbers within the max and min range infinitely.

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class random_unfinished {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numofgen, max, min, generated, avg, i;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random random = new Random();
    System.out.println("How many numbers would you like to     generate?");
    numofgen = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What is the maximum number?");
    max = scan.nextInt() + 1;
    System.out.println("What is the minimum number?");
    min = scan.nextInt();
    for (int value = min; value <= max;) {
      value = random.nextInt(max - min) + min;
      System.out.println("numbers are " + value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes? And what is the problem you’re having?

Comment: The problem is that it keeps on generating the numbers in the max to min range infinetly, sorry i forgot to put it i just made an account today

Comment: How is it related to a javascript?

Comment: java !== javascript

Comment: as much as pain is related to painting

Comment: @JaromandaX in my experience painting is more painful than javascript is javaful.

Comment: bazinga @MarkMeyer

Comment: sorry, got confused because i was looking for other things, i used BlueJ and it is java yikes

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444019/how-do-i-generate-a-random-integer-between-min-and-max-in-java

Comment: Feedback: I have downvoted for the request for "no hate". Please do try to approach this community in a spirit of positivity and enthusiasm! Indeed, people do sometimes get a sharp response here (when they present an unformatted or poorly researched question), but it would be inappropriate to say that is anything close to the level of "hate". Hate is war, racism, violence, significant injustice, and so forth; to use it on trivial matters devalues its power considerably.

Comment: sorry I’m a teenage boy so I usually go on like 4chan or Reddit where it’s filled with hate and extreme racism,I had that mindset.will keep this in mind! Thank you!

Comment: Noted, and vote withdrawn. I appreciate a positive response to feedback `:=)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so the for loop is problematic.

Get used to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
```

if your for loop doesn't look like that, unless you're quite advanced you're probably doing it wrong.

In your case for instance:

```
    for (int value = min; value <= max;) {
```

You initialise a variable called value to be the minimum.
Your test to continue is whether value is less than max (which it will be unless min is greater than max)
The thing you do each time after executing the body of the loop is ... nothing.

Hence you loop infinitely.

Compare with the gold standard:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
```

It initialises a variable i to 0
Its test whether to continue is if i is less than a certain number n
After each execution of the body of the loop it increments i.

Ergo - unless we do something naughty to i, (or do an early exit with a break or return) we will repeat the body of the loop n times.

Cf:

```
    for (int value = min; value <= max; [_____you forgot this bit____] ) {
```

Comment: @Yua-Shimmura - add them to what?  To each other (e.g. to have a total at the end?)  If so then make a variable outside of the loop (e.g. 'int total = 0;') and then each time through in the body of the loop do something like this: 'total += value;'

Comment: actually, your response is incorrect. It is not mandatory to augment the value of value in the for declaration. he's already updating the value here: value = random.nextInt(max - min) + min; But, seeing as he always overwrites, it might take a very long time until value becomes so high it breaks out of the loop.

Comment: @Stultuske surely it can never break out, because `rand(max-min) + min < max`. However, you are absolutely correct to say that the `ForUpdate` is not required - `for (;;);` is a valid (if useless) for loop.

Comment: @Stultuske good point.  If he's going to twiddle the value inside the loop body then incrementing it is redundant, however if that is the case then he absolutely shouldn't be using it as a loop counter anyway, which is what I was trying to subtly steer him towards creating a separate counter - as per the common idiom.

Comment: @Rick if the augmentation should be a fixed one (for instance, +1 each iteration), then yes, but if it's a variable value overwrite/augmentation, that's not always so

Comment: @Stultuske - you misunderstand.  I'm not saying that he must always increment by one, but that until he knows what he's doing that's a good pattern to follow.  In any case your finger wagging is misplaced because in the scenario you describe a while loop would be better anyway.

Comment: @Rick one could argue the differ. with this approach, the value variable only exists in the scope of the loop, with the while it would be outside it as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your for-loop is going from `min` to `max`. Also, it is missing an update clause—which means that `value` never changes. Hence, you’re stuck with an infinite loop.

Instead, you should go from `0` to `numofgen` and make sure to update your `i` by 1 each time. This will generate as many numbers as the user desires.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class random_unfinished {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numofgen, max, min, generated, avg, i;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random random = new Random();
    System.out.println("How many numbers would you like to     generate?");
    numofgen = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What is the maximum number?");
    max = scan.nextInt() + 1;
    System.out.println("What is the minimum number?");
    min = scan.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < numofgen; i++) {
      value = random.nextInt(max - min) + min;
      System.out.println("numbers are " + value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you think that the second line in this: for (int value = min; value <= max;) {
      value = random.nextInt(max - min) + min; does not alter the value of value?

Comment: @Stultuske fair enough I did not consider that!

Comment: it'll no doubt be part of the problem, seeing as he doesn't augment, but rather overwrites the value (with a possible lower one), but it should be able to (eventually) break out of the loop